# html2canvas producing blank image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use html2canvas to take a screenshot of an editable table. But when the page is at full width, it produces a blank image.

Here's what I mean:

[image]

But when I'm on chrome's device tool bar and the size of the page is smaller, it works, but only sometimes.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>PC Setup</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1294px)" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1294px)" href="mobile.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <img src="./images/logo.png" title="Aeron" alt="logo" class="header-logo">
        <div class="desktop-nav">
            <ul class="desktop-nav-links">
                <li><a href="index.html" class="hyperlink">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="hyperlink">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" class="hyperlink">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" class="hyperlink">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="recipes.html" class="hyperlink">Recipes</a></li>
                <li><a href="progress.html" class="hyperlink">Progress</a></li>
                <li><a href="pcsetup.html" class="hyperlink">PC Setup Designer</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html" class="hyperlink">Gallery</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="mobile-nav">
            <span class="menu-button" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
            <div id="mobile-nav-panel" class="mobile-nav-panel">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                <ul class="mobile-nav-link-list">
                    <li class="mobile-nav-link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <hr>
                    <li class="mobile-nav-link"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <hr>
                    <li class="mobile-nav-link"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <hr>
                    <li class="mobile-nav-link"><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <hr>
                    <li class="mobile-nav-link"><a href="recipes.html">Recipes</a></li>
                    <hr>
                    <li class="mobile-nav-link"><a href="progress.html">Progress</a></li>
                    <hr>
                    <li class="mobile-nav-link"><a href="pcsetup.html">PC Setup Designer</a></li>
                    <hr>
                    <li class="mobile-nav-link"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                    <hr>
                    <li class="mobile-nav-link"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="heading">PC Setup Designer</h1>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/html2canvas@1.0.0-rc.5/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Define the function 
        // to screenshot the div
        function takeshot() {
            let table =
                document.getElementById('photo');

            // Use the html2canvas
            // function to take a screenshot
            // and append it
            // to the output div
            html2canvas(table).then(
                function (canvas) {
                    document
                        .getElementById('output')
                        .appendChild(canvas);
                })
        }
    </script>
    <div class="table-container" >
        <table id="photo">
            <tr>
                <th>Part</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>RAM</td>
                <td contenteditable="true" placeholder="Type"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CPU</td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Storage</td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Storage (Optional)</td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>GPU</td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Motherboard</td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <button onclick="takeshot()" class="scrn_button">Take Screenshot</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="output" class="output"></div>
    <br>
    <div style="height:100%"></div>
    <footer>
        <img src="./images/logo.png" title="Aeron" alt="logo" class="footer-logo">
        <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2022 Aeron Corporation</p>
        <div class="footer-links">
            <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
            <p>|</p>
            <a href="policy.html">Policy</a>
            <p>|</p>
            <a href=contact.html>Contact Us</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <button onclick="topFunction()" id="return" title="Return To Top"><img src="./images/return_to_top.png" width="30px"
            alt="Return"></button>
    <script>
        let mybutton = document.getElementById("return");
        window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };
        function scrollFunction() {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
                mybutton.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                mybutton.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        function topFunction() {
            document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        }
        function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("mobile-nav-panel").style.width = "100%";
        }

        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("mobile-nav-panel").style.width = "0";
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

main.css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #0000ff);
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.heading {
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.favcolorcontainer {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.colorpicker {
    border: none;
    background: white;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.favcolor {
    font-family: verdana;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.slideshow-container {
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}

.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
    background-color: #a6a6a650;
}

.slide-name {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.slide-number {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.fade {
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

.progress-bar {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 3px;
}

.progress-tag {
    color: #DDDDDD;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.fill-html {
    width: 75%;
    background-color: #FA3200;
    border-radius: 100px;
}


.fill-css {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #0000C8;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.fill-js {
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #C80000;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.fill-php {
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #00C832;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.fill-rwpd {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #450099;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

#return {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 35px;
    z-index: 99;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #0000d1;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-size: 45px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;

}

#return:hover {
    background-color: #0101bb;
}

.progress-container {
    padding: 10px;
}

.header-logo {
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

.header {
    background-color: #303030;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.desktop-nav-links {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.desktop-nav-links a {
    margin: 20px 25px 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
}

.desktop-nav-links a:hover {
    color: #b4b4b4;
    transition: 0.2s all ease;
}

.desktop-nav-links li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu-button {
    display: none;
}

.copyright {
    color: #b4b4b4;
    font-size: 15px;

}

footer {
    background: #303030;
    padding: 25px 0;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.hyperlink {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #b4b4b4;
}

.hyperlink:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.hyperlink:hover:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #111111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.recipe-container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    justify-content: center;
}

.recipe-window {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    word-break: break-word;
    width: min-content;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.recipe-title {
    color: black;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

:root {
    color-scheme: dark;
}

.footer-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.footer-links p {
    margin: 0;
}

.footer-links a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.footer-links a:hover {
    color: #b4b4b4;
}

.about {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 300px;
}

.mobile-nav {
    display: none;
}

.footer-logo {
    width: 150px;
}

.table-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    justify-content: center;
}

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

td,
th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 50px 10px 10px;
}

th {
    font-size: 20px;
}

td {
    font-size: 15px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.output {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

mobile.css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #0000ff);
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.heading {
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.slideshow-container {
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}

.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
    background-color: #a6a6a650;
}

.slide-name {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.slide-number {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.fade {
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

.progress-bar {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 3px;
}

.progress-tag {
    color: #DDDDDD;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.fill-html {
    width: 75%;
    background-color: #FA3200;
    border-radius: 100px;
}


.fill-css {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #0000C8;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.fill-js {
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #C80000;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.fill-php {
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #00C832;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.fill-rwpd {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #450099;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

#return {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -1000px;
}

.progress-container {
    padding: 10px;
}

.header-logo {
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

.header {
    background-color: #303030;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.desktop-nav {
    display: none;
}

.menu-button {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    float: right;

}

.copyright {
    color: #b4b4b4;
    font-size: 15px;

}

footer {
    background: #303030;
    padding: 25px 0;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.hyperlink {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #b4b4b4;
}

.hyperlink:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.hyperlink:hover:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.recipe-container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    justify-content: center;
}

.recipe-window {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    word-break: break-word;
    width: min-content;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.recipe-title {
    color: black;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.recipe-thumbnail {
    max-width: 350px;
}

:root {
    color-scheme: dark;
}

.footer-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.footer-links p {
    margin: 0;
}

.footer-links a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.footer-links a:hover {
    color: #b4b4b4;
}

.about {
    text-align: center;
}

.mobile-nav {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.mobile-nav-panel {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #111111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.mobile-nav a {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.mobile-nav-panel .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.mobile-nav-link-list {
    margin-right: 25px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    font-size: 1px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
}

.mobile-nav-link {
    padding: 25px 0;
    font-size: 1px;
}

.footer-logo {
    width: 125px;
}

.table-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    justify-content: center;
}

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    max-width: 340px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

td,
th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

th {
    font-size: 15px;
}

td {
    font-size: 10px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you're using a very old version of html2canvas (from 2019).  Try the latest version: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/html2canvas@1.4.1/dist/html2canvas.min.js`

Comment: @yoduh that worked, thank you! The image is still a bit blurry though, how can I fix this?

Comment: @BravoLima2k4 Please can you view my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer on Github solved my problem. I had the same issue.

In case anyone wants the library you can check here. Time of posting link is available :
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/html2canvas

My Solution for blank screen issue :

```
var div = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
//
html2canvas(div, {
    scrollX: 0,
    scrollY: 0,
    width: 340,
    height: 491
}).then(function(canvas) {
    output.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

GitHub article :

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/882#issuecomment-698121822